# Integrating Google Places API with a Rails Application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3, slim-lang

I'm using an Address Autocomplete form field in my Rails 4 application.

Here's the Javascript:

```
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initialize() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
  // to geographical location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
      { types: ['geocode'] });
  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
  // populate the address fields in the form.
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    fillInAddress();
  });
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
          position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

and the HTML (using [Slim](http://www.slim-lang.com) because > HTML syntax)

```
= form_for @post, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|

  .field#locationField = f.text_field :address, id: "autocomplete", placeholder:"Address", onFocus: "geolocate()"

  .field#locality = f.text_field :city, placeholder: "City"
```

The #locationField autocompletes as it should. The problem is that I'd like to populate the #locality field with the City from the Address autocomplete function.

I've got it so that it can populate a separate input (outside of this form_for tag). Here's what that table looks like:

```
table#address
    tr
      td.label Street address
      td.slimField
        input.field#street_number disabled="true"
      td.wideField colspan="2"
        input.field#route disabled="true"
    tr
      td.label City
      td.wideField colspan="3"
        input.field#locality disabled="true"
    tr
      td.label State
      td.slimField
        input.field#administrative_area_level_1 disabled="true"
      td.label Zip code
      td.wideField 
        input.field#postal_code disabled="true"
    tr
      td.label Country
      td.wideField colspan="3"
        input.field#country disabled="true"
```

How can I get my form to save the city?

Any input/ideas are appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what gem did you use for this functionality?

Comment: which functionality?

Comment: to auto-complete an address in a form field

Comment: I am currently working to add autocomplete for address field in a form for my project using the 'gmaps-autocomplete-rails' but I am having issues, I even post a question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204709/couldnt-find-file-gmaps-autocomplete-with-type-text-css

Comment: I didn't use a gem for the autocomplete functionality. just added a javascript to the assets folder and added some classes along w the `address` id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this line

```
.field#locality = f.text_field :city, placeholder: "City"
```

To this

```
.field = f.text_field :city, placeholder: "City", id: 'locality'
```

and it's working like a charm :)